# Laravel Model query when foreign is on the other table

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I have two models Document(having name as one of the columns) and ApplicationDocument. ApplicationDocument contains the foreign key (docucument_id). I want to fetch records from
 documents that are related to the applicationDocument and also match the name criteria.

My relationship looks like this in ApplicationDocument

```js
public function document()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Document', 'doc_id');
    }
```

And looks like this in Document:

```js
public function applicationDocument()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ApplicationDocument');
            
    }
```

And my query looks like this:

```js
$previousDoc= Document::whereHas('applicationDocument', function (Builder $query) {
                    $query->where('application_id', $appID);
                })->where('name', $name)->get();
```

My query is throwing errors. What am I missing please?

Comment: what's the error msg?

Comment: @TsaiKoga Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\ApplicationController::App\Traits\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Traits\Builder, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder

Comment: The foreign_key is `doc_id` or `docucument_id` or `document_id`?

Comment: @TsaiKoga foreign key is doc_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These code is in trait, you are using **Type hinting**. However, laravel will assuming the namespace of `Builder` is `App\Traits`. So the error occurs.

You can add this line at the top of your trait:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
```

or remove type-hinting `Builder`.

---

And by convention, Eloquent will take the "snake case" name of the owning model and suffix it with `_id`. So by default eloquent will assuming the foreign_key is `document_id`. However, the foreign_key is `doc_id`, so you need to specify it.

For ApplicationDocument:

```php
public function document()
{
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Document', 'doc_id');
}
```

For Document, recommend to use **plural** method name:

```php
public function applicationDocuments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ApplicationDocument', 'doc_id', 'id');

}
```

Apply `use($appID)` for injecting the `$appID` to closure.

```php
$previousDoc= Document::whereHas('applicationDocuments', function (Builder $query) use ($appID) {
                    $query->where('application_id', $appID);
                })->where('name', $name)->get();
```

Comment: I still get the error Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\ApplicationController::App\Traits\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Traits\Builder, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder given, called in .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php on line 1008 in file .../app/Traits/File.php on line 102
Stack trace:

Comment: @mykoman are u using some traits function in ApplicationController?

Comment: Yes I am using traits function

Comment: which file would you have me post because my query is actually in the trait function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211602/discussion-between-tsaikoga-and-mykoman).